# Is there a noun for an intentionally simplified task?

Tags: nouns

Similar to "dumbed-down" but a noun, with a stress on the ease of task execution. 
E.g. "The manager asked for expedited reviews of contributions because he wanted the project to be a(n) '-----'"

Comment: A prototype perhaps ?

Comment: Yeah, the way I described it, prototype comes to mind. The intent for simplification here is to finish the task quicker, not to demonstrate anything.

Comment: ok. Worth clarifying this by editing the above question. BTW an example sentence with a `____` where the  word/phrase should go, is usually required on this site for questions like this.

Comment: @k Edited the question

Comment: Sample, demo, model.

Comment: a rush-job (=quick and bad)? a priority (=done ahead of others)? a cake-walk (=easy)? I think you need to clarify if you mean something done quickly and badly, something that overrides all other tasks/priorities and takes people off other work, or (that favorite of project managers) something done as well as possible but in half the time, in which case the word "unicorn" might be appropriate.

Comment: @Stuart F "Unicorn" is what I was looking for, can you post it as an answer, along with the definition?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest the word **breeze**

> **Breeze**
>   [ breez ]
>   noun
>   1 a wind or current of air, especially a light or moderate one.
>   2 a wind of 4–31 miles per hour (2–14 m/sec).
>   3 Informal. **an easy task; something done or carried on without difficulty:**    *Finding people to join in the adventure was a breeze.*
>   4 Chiefly British Informal. a disturbance or quarrel.
>
> Source: online dictionary https://www.dictionary.com/browse/breeze?s=t

Meaning 3 seems a possibility if you don't mind it being informal.
Not exactly what you have asked for but in the context of the example you give I think it can imply that the manager did not want to expend much effort and that short-cuts should be taken.